# Wrong result when converting temperatures

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am the getting wrong result in my python 2.7 interpreter on ubuntu 12.04.
I have tried this code in an online interpreter and the code is ok.

```
#print temperature

kindc = str(raw_input("Please type c for celsius or f for fareneit  "))
tempc = float(raw_input("please type the number of degrees you want to convert   "))

def result(kind,temp):
    if kind == "c":
        result1 = float((temp-32)*9/5)
        return result1
    else:
        result1 = float(5/9*(temp-32))
        return result1

print result(kindc,tempc)
```

Comment: What results are you getting, what did you expect to get instead? What online interpreter did you use to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, `5/9` uses floor division because both operands are integers. Force floating point division by making at least one of the arguments a float:

```
result1 = (5.0 / 9.0) * (temp - 32)
```

The Celsius conversion most likely won't suffer from this, because the `(temp - 32) * 9` outcome is most likely already a float, but it's best to be consistent here:

```
result1 = (temp * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32
```

Note that you need to use the correct formula here; add `+ 32` after multiplying by 9 fifths. Neither formula needs to cast the result to a `float()` here; the output is already going to be a floating point value.

If you used an online Python interpreter that uses Python 3, then your code would have worked as the `/` operator is not a true division operation (always results in a float value). It could also be that that interpreter has:

```
from __future__ import division
```

import that switches Python 2 to the Python 3 behaviour.

The final conversion function is then:

```
def result(kind, temp):
    if kind == "c":
        result1 = (temp * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32
        return result1
    else:
        result1 = 5.0 / 9.0 * (temp - 32)
        return result1
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the celsius-to-fahrenheit conversion to be:

```
 result1 = float(temp)*9/5+32
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's the correct formula, what's your problem?

Comment: Your first revision was quite different. I see now what you mean, the conversion formula itself is also problematic. But the problem is that the Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion is using floor division instead of true division.

Comment: Does Python guarantee left-to-right evaluation of equal-precedence operators? That is, will `float(temp)*9/5` always be treated the same as `(float(temp)*9)/5` and never `float(temp)*(9/5)`

Comment: @chepner just so long as *one* of the numbers in the division term are `float` the division will be carried out in `float` *eg* you could drop the `float` and use `5.0`